# Multiple filter transition

Tags: css

I'm using 2 filter property for a image to become white on hover.

```
.uni-im img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

I want to use transition for a smooth view.

```
.uni-im img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
    transition: filter .15s linear;
}
```

But this transition runs for both property. I mean a transition for brightness and another transition for invert.
**I want to become white directly**, without seeing black image. Is that possible with pure css?

Example:

```css
div {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background 2s linear;
}
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: filter 2s linear;
}

div:hover {
  background: #3F85CE;
}
div:hover img {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal, complete, verifiable example *in the question itself*, rather than on an external website.

Comment: @TylerRoper Got it, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without resorting to some ugly methods. For example, have two images laid on top of eachother. The bottom one is blue, the top is white. The top/white one has `opacity: 0`.  When the div is hovered, transition the white image to `opacity: 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to see the effect, I have created a new snippet, where the color of the image is instead a background.

But it will work the same for your use case.

Just change the filters that you are applying

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: cyan;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: filter 4s;
}

.test:hover {
  filter:  grayscale(1) brightness(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: With this way i see blue -> very light aqua -> white. But its really hard to see, thank you! Better than the black or web fonts etc. You saved my day

Comment: - Actullay with .15s transition, its impossible to see, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Happy that it helped !   You could get rid of the intermediate light aqua, but you would need another html element, so I think it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: i totally agree :)

Answer (score -3):

The codepen you provided has the transition set to 2s. If you shorten the transition time then you don't see the black.

Ex.

```
div {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background 100ms linear;
}
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: filter 100ms linear;
}
```

You can also remove the transition from your image. That way you have the background transition over the course of .15s from white to blue, but the image will switch directly from blue to white without transitioning to black first.

Comment: I know, i did that for the question. But i can see even if i set to .15s

Comment: I'd recommend removing the transition from your image. That way you have the background transition over the course of .15s from white to blue, but the image will switch directly from blue to white without transitioning to black first.

Comment: @jorscobry I'd imagine OP wants the icon to fade from blue --> white, rather than blue --> black --> white, or no fade at all as you suggest.